# How to handle self signed certificates without setting NSAllowArbitraryLoads to yes?

Tags: ios, swift, ssl, tvos

I'm pretty new to swift and I'm trying to figure out how to send some POST requests to a server with self signed certificates. I'm trying to hit a development server for testing right now. This is how I implemented the didReceive challenge function:

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
    let method = challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod
    let host = challenge.protectionSpace.host
    NSLog("challenge %@ for %@", method, host)
    switch (method, host) {
    case (NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust, "mydomain.example.com"):
        let trust = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!
        let credential = URLCredential(trust: trust)
        completionHandler(.useCredential, credential)
    case (NSURLAuthenticationMethodClientCertificate, "mydomain.example.com"):
        completionHandler(.performDefaultHandling, nil)
    default:
        completionHandler(.cancelAuthenticationChallenge, nil)
    }
```

And this is what my Info.plist source looks like to make the call work:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>mydomain.example.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

I've been researching about how to do this online and it seems like this might not be the safest method - what are the risks to setting NSAllowsArbitraryLoads to true? I tried removing that bit but then I would get this error:

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made."
```

And I can't figure out if there's a way to do this without NSAllowsArbitraryLoads enabled. Any advice on this? Would this be okay if it's only for testing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` should never be used, even in testing. Maybe you just forget to delete this parameter in production and all security is gone. Also, it is better to test against a server with real certificates to detect possible errors and security problems.

If you have no special setup, it should be relatively easy to get a free server certificate from [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/). Those certificates are accepted by Apple devices and everything will work.

The other possibility is to create your own certificate authority (CA) and export the CA certificate to your device. Your device will then accept all certificates signed by this CA. Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48486526/5804550) from me to get the details.